# Android WebView saving app state

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I'm trying to make an Android app is that mostly content displayed through a WebView.
I want it to load the most recent app state during `onStart`:

- Load state from storage (`SharedPreferences` to be specific)
- Send state to webpage via `evaluateJavascript`

And I want to save the app state during `onStop`:

- Ask webpage for current app state via `evaluateJavascript`
- webpage sends back app state via `addJavascriptInterface`
- Hopefully at some point, Android saves that state to storage (back to `SharedPreferences`)

This way, if my app process dies (for whatever reason), the most recent app state will usually be saved.

However, it seems that when `onStart` is first invoked (when the app loads), the webpage is most likely not loaded yet.
Therefore, it seems like I need to track whether the webpage has loaded via `WebViewClient.onPageFinished`, and then do some complicated stuff like

- sending the app state to the webpage inside `onPageFinished`
- `onStart`/`onStop` behave differently whether the page has loaded or not.

This seems like a lot of work for a common scenario, I was wondering if there is alternative, standard approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask`to load website in `webview` and it notifies when complete with `onPostExecute`method running after it.
This way you can track whether page is loaded or not